# Handling Rails 5 Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set a time limit to my users' session, I've read that I could define this limit on `config/intializers/session_store.rb` but my project doesn't seem to have this file.
Currently I have this:

```
    def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 2.minutes
  end
```

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: You didn't use any Web Authentication gem ? like devise, authlogic .... If so you can find config option buildin gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config/initializers/session_store.rb` is not generated in Rails 5.1.1+. But, more importantly, you seem to misunderstand initializer files. They are loaded once during the application server startup period. They are often arbitrary Ruby code that could all be executed in a single file, but are separated for the sake of simplicity and modularity.

You are free to create `/config/initializers/session_store.rb` and it will load any Ruby on Rails code on startup.

```
$ touch config/initializers/session_store.rb
$ vim config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

Inside of `session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 2.minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for the englightment, I'll do as you told and test here.